# Remove Android status bar gradient

Tags: notification-bar

Is it possible to remove the black-to-transparent gradient that, as of Kit Kat, is now behind the status bar and the home button?

I find it to be rather ugly and would rather it be gone.

Comment: I have yet to find a way. It is transparent to avoid screen burn, but graded... just because from what I can tell. I guess it stays legible with bright wallpaper. You can't change any of the notification yourself without an alternative ROM or at least something like Xposed, but even in Xposed (or the new Nova Launcer) the gradient is still there. I'm beginning to think it's there to stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the status and navigation bars to have the transparent gradient is handled by applications/launchers themselves in stock 4.4. Some apps and launchers provide a setting to turn the gradients on and off.

The AOSP launcher always uses opaque bars, Google Now launcher always uses transparent bars, and certain 3rd party launchers such as Nova give you a toggle. Regardless of the launcher's setting, apps can and will override it.